# MOQ how to mock a class that depends on another class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a class with a constructor like so:

```
public class SsoAuthenticationService : ISsoAuthenticationService
{
  public SsoAuthenticationService(ILoginManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }
}
```

And also the manager class has a constructor like so:

```
 public class LoginManager:ILoginManager
 {
    private ILoginRepository login;

    public LoginManager(ILoginRepository loginRepository)
    {
        login = loginRepository;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to write a unit test against the SSoAuthenticationService class

```
    public void CreateLogin_Returns_Login()
    {
        //arrange
        var mocManager = new Mock<ILoginManager>();

        ILoginManager m = mocManager.Object;

        //fails at the next line
        var svc = new SsoAuthenticationService(mocManager.Object);
        var request = new CreateSsoLoginRequest()
                          {
                              EmailAddress = "",
                              Password = "",
                              SecurityQuestionAnswer = "",
                              SecurityQuestionId = 0,
                              SiteIdentifier = "",
                              Username = ""
                          };

        //act
        var response = svc.CreateSsoLogin(request);

        //assert
        response.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
```

This gives an error when it tries to instantiate the `SsoAuthenticationService` class (`"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value"`), and I believe that the problem is that I need to also mock the `IRepository` class as well, but I'm not sure how the mocking code should then look.

**Edit**: Full exception info

> The type initializer for 'Progressive.Sso.WebServices.SsoAuthenticationService' threw an exception.
>   Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value
>   at Progressive.Sso.WebServices.SsoAuthenticationService..ctor(ILoginManager manager)
>   at Progressive.Sso.Tests.Service_Methods.ServiceTest.CreateLogin_Returns_Login() in d:\tfs\sso\Dev\Dev\Src\SSO Web Services\Progressive.Sso.Tests\Service Methods\ServiceTest.cs:line 29

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide the full exception information sunch as the stacktrace. Also what does CreateSsoLogin do against the `ILoginManager`?

Comment: It doesn't get as far as calling CreateSsoLogin, the code fails when the SsoAuthenticationService is instantiated

Comment: Do you have any static fields not shown above?

Comment: Very prophetic - aqwert, just noticed your comment after I posted my answer. Static methods were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, and the problem is nothing to do with Moq, or the constructor dependencies.

I had the following two member variables declared

```
private static readonly bool _useOperationTimer = SsoConfig.UseServiceOperationTimer;
private static readonly bool _logRequestData = SsoConfig.LogRequestData;
```

The static method calls were the cause of the issue, if they are commented out everything works.